# Photoresistor Matrix has the same values

Tags: arduino-uno, multiplexer, pcb-design, photoresistor

I'm a second-year System Engineer student who needs to make a project for class.
I have a 4x4 matrix of photoresistors that goes to an analog digital multiplexer connected to an Arduino Uno. This setup is put in a box with a lid. The lid has a hole in the middle of the matrix. I want to calculate the angle of a light source depending on the photoresistors' readings. Basically, I want to recreate a Sattelite Sun Sensor.
I have the following problem: all the photoresistors from a row have the same reading, even if I try to isolate one of them and shine a light on it. In the column, everything works well.

This is my circuit on a 2 layers PCB:
(C0-C15, SIG, S0-S3, EN are the pins of the CD74HC4067 Multiplexer)
[image: PCB Board]
[image: Circuit Schematic]

Also, this is my code:

```
//Mux control pins
int s0 = 11;
int s1 = 10;
int s2 = 9;
int s3 = 8;

//Mux in "SIG" pin
int SIG_pin = 0;
float values[4][4] = {0.0};

void setup(){
  pinMode(s0, OUTPUT); 
  pinMode(s1, OUTPUT); 
  pinMode(s2, OUTPUT); 
  pinMode(s3, OUTPUT); 

  digitalWrite(s0, LOW);
  digitalWrite(s1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(s2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(s3, LOW);

  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop(){

  //Loop through and read all 16 values
  for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
      for(int j = 0; j < 4; ++j){
        values[i][j] = readMux(i);
        delay(500);
      }

  Serial.println("-----Matrix-----");
  for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i){
      for(int j = 0; j < 4; ++j){
        Serial.print(values[i][j]);
        Serial.print(" ");
        delay(100);
    }
    Serial.println();
  }
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print(calculateAngle());
  Serial.println();
  delay(1000);
}

float calculateAngle(){
  const int dx[] = {-2, -1, 1, 2, -2, -1, 1, 2, -2, -1, 1, 2, -2, -1, 1, 2};
  const int dy[] = {-2, -2, -2, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2};
  float x = 0, y = 0;

  for(int i = 0; i < 16; ++i){
    x += dx[15 - i] * values[i / 4][i % 4];
    y += dy[15 - i] * values[i / 4][i % 4];
  }
  Serial.print(x);
  Serial.print(" ");
  Serial.print(y);
  Serial.print(" ");
  return atan2(y, x) * 180 / 3.14;
}

float readMux(int channel){
  int controlPin[] = {s0, s1, s2, s3};

  int muxChannel[16][4]={
    {0,0,0,0}, //channel 0
    {1,0,0,0}, //channel 1
    {0,1,0,0}, //channel 2
    {1,1,0,0}, //channel 3
    {0,0,1,0}, //channel 4
    {1,0,1,0}, //channel 5
    {0,1,1,0}, //channel 6
    {1,1,1,0}, //channel 7
    {0,0,0,1}, //channel 8
    {1,0,0,1}, //channel 9
    {0,1,0,1}, //channel 10
    {1,1,0,1}, //channel 11
    {0,0,1,1}, //channel 12
    {1,0,1,1}, //channel 13
    {0,1,1,1}, //channel 14
    {1,1,1,1}  //channel 15
  };
  DDRB = 0;
  //loop through the 4 sig
  for(int i = 0; i < 4; i ++)
    DDRB |= (1 << i) & muxChannel[channel][i]; //faster than digitalWrite(controlPin[i], muxChannel[channel][i]);
  delay(100);
  //read the value at the SIG pin
  int val = analogRead(SIG_pin);
  //convert the value in voltage
  float voltage = (val * 5.0) / 1024.0;
  //return the voltage
  return voltage;
}
```

Example of a bogus reading:

```
-----Matrix-----
0.13 0.14 0.13 0.12 
3.14 3.17 3.12 2.96 
0.12 0.12 0.11 0.12 
2.77 2.81 2.83 2.77
```

What am I doing wrong? Did I make a mistake in my code or connecting everything together? Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably, because you don't actually set the MUX pins. The `DDRx` registers set the **D**ata **D**irection of the port pins. A 1 in there means, that the pin corresponding to that bit is set as output. A zero means, it is set as input. The output state of a pin is controlled by the `PORTx` registers. If the `DDRx` bits are set to input and the `PORTx` bits are set to 1, then the internal pullup resistor is activated.

In setup you set all the MUX pins to OUTPUT and LOW, so `DDRB` with 1s and `PORTB` with zeros. Then in `readMux()` you are just setting bits in `DDRB` via the (overcomplicated) line:

```
DDRB |= (1 << i) & muxChannel[channel][i];
```

So you are switching the pins between OUTPUT+LOW and INPUT+NO_PULLUP. Instead you should write to the `PORTB` register, which controls the output state of the port B pins.

Also writing the mux channel can be done way easier. When you look at your array in `readMux()` you might notice, that the channel patters are just a binary number. So you have the following channel number to pattern relationship:

```
channel  0 --> binary 0000 --> decimal 0
channel  1 --> binary 0001 --> decimal 1
channel  2 --> binary 0010 --> decimal 2
channel  3 --> binary 0011 --> decimal 3
...
channel 10 --> binary 1010 --> decimal 10
...
```

So instead of using the above overcomplicated line, you can just write the channel number to the 4 target bits of `PORTB`:

```
PORTB |= channel & 0b00001111;
```

You don't even need to for loop for that. The `& 0b00001111` part is only for cutting the channel number to only ever use the first 4 bits of the register (keeping it down between 0 and 15).

Comment: So this solved one of the problems. The main one was that I was reading just 4 channels 4 times instead of all different 16, thus why the values were similar. Thank you so much for helping me and for the code optimization!